# Deploy all MSIs from a folder-share to group of computers via domain group-policy?

Tags: group-policy, deployment

Is it possible to deploy **all** MSI packages within a folder-share to a group of computers, with a single group-policy object?

If so, how?

Comment: If a computer startup script is acceptable, a simple batch file like: `FOR %%A IN (\\server\path\msis\*.msi) DO ( msiexec /i "%%A" /qn )` -- however I suspect you want a bit more control that that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean as separate and distinct Software Install packages in the same GPO or as a single, monolithic install? If it's the former then yes, if it's the latter then no.

Comment: +1.  The latter is "no" unless he creates a "wrapper" MSI which pulls in the subordinate MSIs in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just use the Assigned Applications feature in Group Policy to push out the MSIs.